# Connection To MongoDb running in Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I'm really new in using Docker and now I'm trying to run a Mongodb in a Docker locally and get a Connection to it. I don't know why but I can't get any Connection.

Setup: I am using a Mac with MacOS Catalina 10.15.4
 - Docker Desktop Version 2.2.0.5

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

RUN echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' > tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y mongodb

RUN mkdir -p /data/db

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["--port 27017"]

ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod
```

after this I run these Commands:

1. docker build -t testmongodb .
2. docker run -p 27017:27017 testmongodb

I can see the Image runnig in Docker Desktop
and I try to use Studio 3T to Connect to the Mongodb
my Url for this is: mongodb://localhost:27017/?serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000&connectTimeoutMS=10000&3t.uriVersion=3&3t.connection.name=localhost%3A27017
The Error I get is:

```
Connection failed.

SERVER [localhost:27017] (Type: UNKNOWN) 
|_/ Connection error (MongoSocketReadException): Prematurely reached end of stream

Details:
Timed out after 5000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The mongod instance by default only listens on the loopback interface `127.0.0.1`. In this case this means the loopback interface *inside* the container. To also have it listen for external connections you need to specify a separate ip:

```
ENTRYPOINT usr/bin/mongod --bind_ip 0.0.0.0
```

As an aside, rolling your own docker image for something like mongodb, which has an [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) already, is rarely a good idea unless you know what you're doing or need more than the official image can provide.

Comment: Hmm at this point it can realistically only be your firewall that's stopping you. Unless you have some weird network-card configurations running. I managed to connect to this configuration from robo 3t without any trouble.